# How to get image from zip archive to gd without extracting?

Tags: php, zip, gd

As in the title, that's what I tried:

```
$src_im = imagecreatefrompng("zip://maps.zip#gfx/tiles/default_dust.png");
```

and

```
$res = $zip->open("maps.zip");
$d = $zip->getStream("gfx/tiles/default_dust.png");
$zip->close();
$src_im = imagecreatefromstring($d);
```

but nothing doesn't work

Comment: Please rephrase the question. It's impossible to get anything legible from a zip archive without extracting it first. I guess your question is how to extract one file without extracting all others .

Comment: Yeah @apokryfos you are right. Sadly I can't extract in to memory because of this ZipArchive cannot work with "memory mapped files". Well I'll unzip it to temporary directory. Thank you for an answer.